# Cast object type to another type

Tags: javascript, typescript, casting, type-conversion

I have class where I set type of `range` to `IntervalRange`

```
export class Test {range: IntervalRange;}
```

then in parent class I initialize the value:

```
export class TestInitializer {
Create(){
    return <Test>{
        range: IntervalRange.initialize(Database.GetByName('MONTH').id};
}

InitializeElement() {
  let test = <Test>JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(configuration));
  return test;
}
```

then in my other component I use this as:

```
@Input() range: IntervalRange;
```

However on function `range.getRange();` 
I get: `ERROR TypeError: this.range.getRange is not a function`

Why is that? it says `range` is an Object, though it should be `IntervalRange`.

I tried writing `as IntervalRange`, `<IntervalRange> range`
nothing worked. How to fix that?

Update: `let type = typeof(this.range)`; prints `"object"`

method:

```
ngOnChanges() {
if (this.range) {
  let type = typeof(this.range);
  let ddd = this.range.getRange(); //<----- this is where I get error
}
```

Comment: Please also post the code of the "other component" where you get the error, and the definition of the `IntervalRange` type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typecast only casts the type. Typescript doesn't exist at runtime. Therefore if `JSON.parse` doesn't return a proper `Test` instance (which it won't since methods won't get serialized), it will fail at runtime. Instead of typecasting you probably want to build up a Test instance, and load the serialized data into it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I fixed it by doing ` d = Object.assign(new IntervalRange(), this.range);`

Answer (score 1):

The TypeScript "cast" (`<A>tmp` or `tmp as A`) :

- makes structural type compatibility checking → it is unavailable if the source data has type `any`.
- has no runtime counterpart → TypeScript types can be compatible but runtime types can differ, for instance an object literal vs a real class instance.

When the data comes from an unsafe/external source, e.g. JSON.parse() or a WebAPI call, it's a DTO *(data transfer object)*, with the `any` type. The TypeScript "cast" is unsafe too.

To ensure the cast operation, you can use a mapping function from the DTO to the "domain model" class. The key point is to return a real class instance.

- `Object.assign(new IntervalRange(), this.range)` *(that you mentioned in a comment)* satisfies this point.
- We can be even more stricter with a "field by field mapping": `this.a = range.a; this.b = range.b; ...)`.

Both options are better encaspulated in a function: the class constructor, a static factory method in the class, an external function in the same module.